# I need lightest simplest windows tool like combination of notepad and calender in a fashion of sticky notes?

Tags: windows-xp

I need lightest simplest windows tool like combination of notepad and calender in a fashion of sticky notes , and want to keep always open but should have minimize button.

Answer (score 1):

[Easy Notes](http://www.rawos.com/easynotes) has these features and a bit more. It sits in the tray and has an easily accessible sticky-note interface as well as a calendar:

[image]

[image]

You can even put notes inside the calendar:

[image]

Easy Notes has a freeware "lite" version as well as a paid version available.

Comment: So do you and Molly actually use this stuff or do you just Google?

Comment: @Nathaniel, I still have this installed but I don't really use it any more: http://i49.tinypic.com/117xkzt.png Thunderbird's lightning has essentially replaced it for my needs, but since Thunderbird isn't primarily for this sort of thing, and it isn't exactly 'light', this is my recommendation.

Comment: @Nathaniel It doesn't matter how a respondent gets the information. Many questioners here don't know how to use Google properly, so I try to put the source of my information into my answers - even sometimes a link to the Google query.

Comment: Right. I just got the impression that they did a lot of Google answering, but I also have the impression they're pretty smart and rather widely experienced people. Also, I do think in general that software-rec answers are more credible if the answerer has actually used the software.

Answer (score 1):

**[Rainlendar](http://www.rainlendar.net/cms/index.php)**: highly customizable, skins, multiple calendars, to do list, alarms, recurrence, scripting, backup, printing, search, platform independent, localized, import and export, standards-compatible (iCal).

Pro only: Google Calendar support, Remember The Milk support, shared calendars, Outlook support.

[image] [image] [image]